# Installation of Sharepoint 2010 on VM

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory

I want to install Sharepoint 2010. I have a couple of queries that need addressing:

1. Is it a must I have SQL server 2008 in a separate VM as the Windows Server 2008 R2 where Sharepoint?
2. What are the accounts needed to install Sharepoint? And what group should they each belong to?

I will highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, SQL Server can be on the same box just fine.
2. Accounts need to be Active Directory accounts if SP is installed as farm installation. Setup account is the most important one and needs to be local admin, and during installation it will set permissions for other accounts. There are a number of other accounts as well, which I will not list here as simple search will get you to tens of pages, including MSDN, where accounts are described. See [here](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=391) for example.
3. If you're installing SP in stand-alone mode, simple local admin account on which you run the installation is fine.

Comment: Are you sure the accounts must be AD accounts? For 2013 at least I usually use the Azure VS VM with the built in install script for SP2013, let me have a stand-alone dev environment up and running in 10 minutes fresh installed without AD

Comment: I think even local accounts will suffice.

Comment: True, updated my answer to include standalone scenario.

Comment: You can use even just one for everything (the setup account) if using DEV box with no specific requirements in terms of security.

Comment: Are ALL those accounts mandatory for the sharepoint to work? It's a long list. From previous research, I have found that there are only 3: (i)SP_SQL (Domain user) (ii)SP_Farm(Domain user) (iii)SP_Admin(Domain user,Administrators) @JussiPalo